# Realbasic: How to create a file in a specific folder?

Tags: realbasic

I think my question is quite simple, but I can't find a solution.

I want to create a file in a folder that's located near the application file (MacOS).

To create a new folder:

```
dim fi as FolderItem = getFolderItem( "MyFolder" )
fi.CreateAsFolder
```

And now I need to get a `FolderItem` for the file inside this folder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you pretty close to what you want.

```
dim fi as FolderItem = getFolderItem( "MyFolder" )
if fi.exists = false then
  fi.CreateAsFolder
end

dim fChild as folderitem = fi.child("someFile")
if fChild.exists = false then
  //Do something like create it.
  //Look at TextOutputStream or similar
else
  //Already exists.  Open it?
end
```